# juniper access list for ipv6 under ex4200

Tags: juniper-junos

I have a ex4200-48p and it is acting as my top of rack switch and i have the following firewall filter under each port :

```
set firewall family ethernet-switching filter port24 term layer2 from ether-type arp
set firewall family ethernet-switching filter port24 term layer2 then accept
set firewall family ethernet-switching filter port24 term port24 from source-address 192.168.0.0/24
set firewall family ethernet-switching filter port24 term port24 then accept
set firewall family ethernet-switching filter port24 term port24-v6 from protocol ipv6
set firewall family ethernet-switching filter port24 term port24-v6 then accept
set firewall family ethernet-switching filter port24 term layer2-v6 from ether-type ipv6
set firewall family ethernet-switching filter port24 term layer2-v6 then accept
set firewall family ethernet-switching filter port24 term default-term then discard
```

with this firewall rules i can limit the port to specific IPv4 sources but i could not find anyway to limit specific IPv6 source address for my clients, and in this rules any kind of ipv6 is allowed,
Can somebody help me?